# How to clean up the mesh around the holes?

Tags: mesh, topology

The holes are connected with the edge, how to remove it, when I delete the edges marked red, the whole face is gone, I do not know why the face is gone, and how to clean up the mesh, at least make it a little nice.

[image]

Another question is how to erase the bevel, to make it 90 degree, as you can see I want to connect face 1 /2,2/3,1/3 and remove the messy bevel between these three faces.

[image]

Comment: In the second picture, i suggest you create a cube mesh that has dimensions similar to that of lengths of faces 1,2,3 and then align the box to the beveled mesh (enable Preferences: Add-ons: "Align Tools" to access in the Tools, Align area (to align location, rotation, scale)... would be the easiest to "get rid of the bevel".    Otherwise you might try to use Edit mode, select one of the bevel faces, then Select -> Similar -> Area, and delete faces, but you'd have to do this for several iterations and then be left with a cleanup of editing and moving the vertices related to faces 1,2 and 3.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. For different and unrelated questions open as many posts as you need.

Comment: I think I have to manually do some operation on the mesh to construct the clean mesh, no easy way